# Select specific columns not working LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to get specific columns with `Select` in `linq`, its returning list of selected columns but when trying get in `.cshtml` page its create an error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Code'

**In Controller:**

```
ViewBag.Data= oDB.Table.Where(x => x.Type == 1).Select(x => new { x.Code, x.Desc }).ToList();
```

**In View:**

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Data)
{
    <li>@item.Code</li>
}
```

Working fine while remove column selection:

```
ViewBag.Data= oDB.Table.Where(x => x.Type == 1).ToList();
```

What the difference?

Comment: The code is the value of the Attribute "class".  Try x.Attribute("class").value.

Comment: The difference is one is an anonymous object, I personally don't know how view's react to that but that's the difference.

Comment: Well someone flag this ques **Off Topic** , Is it really off topic?

Comment: I don't know much about UI but why is your controller setting `ViewBag.Data` and in View you do `ViewBag.Cohorts`. Is it supposed to be like that?

Comment: Thanks @GiladGreen its just mistake while change actual stuff to demo in ques , I've made an edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Cohorts)
{
    <li>@item.Code</li>
}
```

This will not work directly. you have to typecast it to correct object first using typecast or using as keyword

```
var list = (ActualTypeGoesHere)ViewBag.Cohorts;
@foreach (var item in list)
{
    <li>@item.Code</li>
}
```

but since you are using the 'anonymous' type you can't do anything. So you have to create a DTO and then map data to that DTO in the controller and send that DTO to View using model or ViewBag. Then cast the ViewBag to DTO as shown above.

It seems that my answer was not clear to the OP so I am adding EDIT

```
 In View:

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Data)
{
    <li>@item.Code</li>
}
```

The type of item in the foreach loop above is not List its of type dynamic and at runtime it will be -       item.GetType()  {Name = "<>f__AnonymousType1`2" Code = "<>f__AnonymousType1`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"}  dynamic {System.RuntimeType}

you will get type if you do item.GetType(); So now you see that you cannot directly extract out the value of Code from item like you would expect to.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/460614/Difference-between-var-and-dynamic-in-Csharp

Comment: No Its not like that, its working directly but problem while select some specific columns.

Comment: That is what I have explained above. You are using  'anonymous' type and hence it is throwing exception 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Code'. Read about 'anonymous' types. Also problem is not wrt to selecting multiple columns its because of the fact that you are mapping the selected columns to 'anonymous' types. Please understand the answer properly before doing a downvote directly.

Comment: As I already mentioned that `ViewBag.Data= oDB.Table.Where(x => x.Type == 1).ToList();`  this code is working **directly** .

Comment: ViewBag.Data= oDB.Table.Where(x => x.Type == 1).ToList(); This is working becasuse ViewBag.Data at runtime will be List<Table> and not anonymous type. The type of ViewBag is dynamic which means that you can assign anything to it at compile time and compiler will ignore it. But at runtime CLR will throw exception if the property is not valid on the assigned type

Comment: If you are still having doubt then do one thing move the foreach from View to controller directly after line =>  ViewBag.Data= oDB.Table.Where(x => x.Type == 1).Select(x => new { x.Code, x.Desc }).ToList(); line and execute the code. See if it throws exception. It will. It's nothing to do with MVC. Its pure C#.

Comment: No, you cannot typecast because the type is an anonymous type. You have to create a DTO like I have mentioned already

Answer (score 0):

the new { x.Code, x.Desc } gives you new data type an unknow type so in this case x.Type will be missing aslo and you don't know what type of object are you gettign back from viewbag.So if you use new Class1 {X.type=1,X.Code,X.Desc} it will pickup the Code property.

The order solution is to use dynamic instead of var in for each loop.